# i want to create a div every 7 items i couldn't

Tags: javascript, css

my data is coming from json file. I want to pass it to a bottom row every 7 data. I want to achieve something like the image in the link.

```
enter code here

       https://codepen.io/tolgagnydnn/pen/ExXaXXX

enter code here
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qtP6t.png

Comment: add your code. lütfen

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap the imgs/divs into another div which have style `display:grid`

```
//Your HTML Code
<div class="grid">
        <div class="div"></div>
        <div class="div"></div>
        <div class="div"></div>
        <div class="div"></div>
        <div class="div"></div>
        <div class="div"></div>
        <div class="div"></div>
        <div class="div"></div>
        <div class="div"></div>
        <div class="div"></div>
        <div class="div"></div>
        <div class="div"></div>
        <div class="div"></div>
        <div class="div"></div>
        <div class="div"></div>
</div>

//CSS
.grid {
       display: grid;
       grid-template-areas: "a a a a a a a";
       gap: 10px;
}
.div {
       height: 100px;
       width: 100px;
       background-color: red;
       display: inline-block;
}
```

Hope you wanted something like that, I really can't know when you don't share much info.

Answer (score 0):

I sent a codepen link, I solved my problem for the codes, now I uploaded the codes. I print after every 7 books by adding a row. I have one question. How can I make the class names at the top dynamic and fill them according to the incoming data?

```js
'use strict'

const books = [
  {
    id: 1,
    bookname: "Kitap Adı Gelecek Uzun olabilir",
    bookimage: "images/book1.png",
    bookClass: "1. Sınıf"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    bookname: "Kitap Adı Gelecek Uzun olabilir",
    bookimage: "images/book1.png",
    bookClass: "1. Sınıf"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    bookname: "Kitap Adı Gelecek",
    bookimage: "images/book2.jpg",
    bookClass: "1. Sınıf"
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    bookname: "Kitap Adı Gelecek",
    bookimage: "images/book2.jpg",
    bookClass: "1. Sınıf"
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    bookname: "Kitap Adı Gelecek",
    bookimage: "images/book2.jpg",
    bookClass: "1. Sınıf"
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    bookname: "Kitap Adı Gelecek",
    bookimage: "images/book2.jpg",
    bookClass: "1. Sınıf"
  },
  {
    id: 7,
    bookname: "Kitap Adı Gelecek",
    bookimage: "images/book2.jpg",
    bookClass: "2. Sınıf"
  },
  {
    id: 8,
    bookname: "Kitap Adı Gelecek",
    bookimage: "images/book1.png",
    bookClass: "2. Sınıf"
  },
  {
    id: 9,
    bookname: "Kitap Adı Gelecek",
    bookimage: "images/book1.png",
    bookClass: "2. Sınıf"
  },
  {
    id: 10,
    bookname: "Kitap Adı Gelecek",
    bookimage: "images/book1.png",
    bookClass: "2. Sınıf"
  },
  {
    id: 11,
    bookname: "Kitap Adı Gelecek",
    bookimage: "images/book1.png",
    bookClass: "2. Sınıf"
  },
  {
    id: 12,
    bookname: "Kitap Adı Gelecek",
    bookimage: "images/book2.jpg",
    bookClass: "2. Sınıf"
  },
  {
    id: 13,
    bookname: "Kitap Adı Gelecek",
    bookimage: "http://srvalle.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/issuu5.jpg",
    bookClass: "2. Sınıf"
  },
  {
    id: 14,
    bookname: "Kitap Adı Gelecek",
   bookimage: "http://srvalle.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/issuu5.jpg",
    bookClass: "2. Sınıf"
  },
  {
    id: 15,
    bookname: "Kitap Adı Gelecek",
    bookimage: "http://srvalle.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/issuu5.jpg",
    bookClass: "3. Sınıf"
  },
  {
    id: 16,
    bookname: "Kitap Adı Gelecek",
    bookimage: "http://srvalle.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/issuu5.jpg",
    bookClass: "3. Sınıf"
  },
  {
    id: 17,
    bookname: "Kitap Adı Gelecek",
   bookimage: "http://srvalle.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/issuu5.jpg",
    bookClass: "3. Sınıf"
  },
  {
    id: 18,
    bookname: "Kitap Adı Gelecek",
  bookimage: "http://srvalle.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/issuu5.jpg",
    bookClass: "3. Sınıf"
  },
  {
    id: 19,
    bookname: "Kitap Adı Gelecek",
    bookimage: "http://srvalle.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/issuu5.jpg",
    bookClass: "3. Sınıf"
  },
  {
    id: 20,
    bookname: "Kitap Adı Gelecek",
    bookimage: "http://srvalle.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/issuu5.jpg",
    bookClass: "3. Sınıf"
  },
  {
    id: 21,
    bookname: "Kitap Adı Gelecek",
    bookimage: "http://srvalle.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/issuu5.jpg",
    bookClass: "3. Sınıf"
  },
  {
    id: 22,
    bookname: "Kitap Adı Gelecek",
    bookimage: "http://srvalle.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/issuu5.jpg",
    bookClass: "3. Sınıf"
  },
  {
    id: 23,
    bookname: "Kitap Adı Gelecek",
    bookimage: "http://srvalle.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/issuu5.jpg",
    bookClass: "3. Sınıf"
  },
]


const isXSmall = window.matchMedia("only screen and (max-width: 576px)").matches;
const isSmall = window.matchMedia("only screen and (max-width: 768px)").matches;
const isMedium = window.matchMedia("only screen and (max-width: 992px)").matches;
const isLarge = window.matchMedia("only screen and (max-width: 1200px)").matches;
const isXLarge = window.matchMedia("only screen and (min-width: 1200px)").matches;

if (isXSmall) {
   var n = 2;
} else if (isSmall) {
   var n = 3;
} 
else if (isMedium) {
    var n = 5;
}
else if (isLarge) {
   var n = 6;
}
else if (isXLarge) {
   var n = 7;
}


const bookshelfbox = document.querySelector('.bookshelfbox');
const bookproduct = document.querySelectorAll('.bookproduct');
const className = document.querySelector('.slides');
const bookproductbox = document.querySelector('.bookproductbox');

const grouredBooks = books.reduce((r, e, i) =>
    (i % n ? r[r.length - 1].push(e) : r.push([e])) && r
, []);



grouredBooks.map((books) => {
  const row = document.createElement('div');
  row.className = 'bookproductbox';
  bookshelfbox.appendChild(row);
  return books.map(
    (book) =>
      (row.innerHTML += `
          <div class="bookproduct">
              <img 
                  src="${book.bookimage}" 
                  alt="" 
                  width="120" 
                  height="180"
                  class="img_thumb" style="width: 120px; height: 180px; top: -73px;"
              >
              <div class="producttitle">
              <p> ${book.bookname} </p>
            </div>
    `)
  );
});
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@300;400;600;800&family=PT+Serif:wght@400;700&display=swap");

*,
html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    font-family: 'PT Serif', serif;
}

body a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

body a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
}

body .form-control:focus {
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: none !important;
}

body button:focus {
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}

body p {
    margin-bottom: 0 !important;
}



.wrapper .booklib {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

.wrapper .booklib .header {
    background: #93643a url('images/header2.png') repeat;
    color: #e4b173;
    width: 100%;
    height: 70px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.wrapper .booklib .header ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    height: 60px;
    width: 100%!important;
}

.wrapper .booklib .header ul li {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 15px!important;
    padding: 4px 8px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: #d39e6b solid 1px;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px rgb(0 0 0 / 40%);
    font-size: 18px;
    opacity: 0.7;
    transform: scale(0.9);
    transition: all .5s ease;
    font-weight: 900;
    width: auto!important;
}

.wrapper .booklib .header ul .flex-active-slide {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: scale(1);
}

.bookshelfbox {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
    float: left;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.bookshelfbox .bookproductbox {
    background: url('images/shelf2.png');
    width: 100%;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
    align-items: center;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    padding: 1rem;
    height: 225px;
}


.bookproduct {
    margin-left: 50px;
    position: relative !important;
    display: block;
    direction: ltr !important;
}

.bookproduct img {
    display: block !important;
    border: none !important;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
}

.producttitle {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    text-align: center !important;
    color: #ffffff;
    background: #c33b4e;
    overflow: hidden;
    max-height: 14px;
    line-height: 14px !important;
    width: 100%;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 8px rgb(0 0 0 / 40%);
    font-size: 11px;
    padding: 1px 5px 3px 5px;
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.bookproduct:hover .producttitle {
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255); 
    background: url(&quot;http://srvalle.com/wp-content/plugins/bookshelf-slider/assets/title_product_bg.png&quot;) repeat rgb(195, 59, 78);
    overflow: visible; 
    max-height: 150px;
}



.flexslider {
    margin:0;
    border:0;
    background: none!important;
}

.flex-nav-prev, .flex-nav-next, .flex-direction-nav {
  display: none!important;
}



@media (max-width: 575.98px) {
    .bookproduct {
        margin-left: 65px;
    }
    .flex-viewport {
        overflow: visible!important;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 576px) and (max-width: 767.98px) {
    .bookproduct {
        margin-left: 30px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991.98px) {
    .bookproduct {
        margin-left: 30px;
    }
}

@media (min-width: 992px) and (max-width: 1199.98px) {
    .bookproduct {
        margin-left: 30px;
    }
}



/* .bookshelfbox {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.bookproductbox, .row {
  display: flex;
} */
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="tr">

<head>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/_tema/cms/images/favicon.png">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Custom CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flexslider/2.7.0/flexslider.min.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">

  <title> TG Book Library </title>

</head>

<body>
  <div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
          <div class="booklib">
            <div class="header">
              <div id="carousel" class="flexslider">
                <ul class="slides">
                  <li>
                    1. Sınıf
                  </li>
                  <li>
                    2. Sınıf
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div id="slider" class="flexslider">
              <ul class="slides">
                <li>
                  <div class="bookshelfbox" data-id="1">
                            
                  </div> 
                </li>
                <li>
                  <div class="bookshelfbox" data-id="2">
                            
                  </div> 
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
           
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--/ container end -->
    </div>
</body>

</html>





<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flexslider/2.7.0/jquery.flexslider.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/app.js"></script>


<script>
  $(window).load(function () {
    // The slider being synced must be initialized first
    $('#carousel').flexslider({
      animation: "slide",
      controlNav: false,
      animationLoop: false,
      slideshow: false,
      itemWidth: 210,
      itemMargin: 5,
      asNavFor: '#slider'
    });

    $('#slider').flexslider({
      animation: "slide",
      controlNav: false,
      animationLoop: false,
      slideshow: false,
      sync: "#carousel"
    });
  });
</script>
```